# Trying to create Area Chart based on same column filter

Tags: tableau-api

As shown in the image , [image] Im trying to create an Area chart of unemployment/1000 peoplein India based on both genders but categorized on Area type(rural or urban).
In this area chart Im trying to use dual axis so that I can filter it based on Type of Area(rural or urban). However dual axis wont work here since rural and urban are part of the same column. How can i create an area chart in this scenario ?

I cannot put area type in color since it will give me aggregated values of both rural and urban. Something like this[image]

Data Set is given below
[image: Data Set]